# Warning :Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, warnings

I am new developer **ReactJS**, I develop a table with ReactJS on the FrontEnd, NodeJS on BackEnd and MySQL about the database. I want to get a data with Select request on the table.

My frontend :

```
class ListeClients extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clients: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios({
      method: "get",
      url: "/app/listeclients/",
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        if (response && response.data) {
          this.setState({ clients: response.data });
        }
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  render() {
    let { clients } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="animated fadeIn">
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Card>
              <CardHeader>
                <h4>
                  <strong>
                    <i className="fa fa-align-justify" /> Tous les clients
                  </strong>
                </h4>
              </CardHeader>
              <CardBody>
                <div className="container">
                  <div className="panel panel-default p50 uth-panel">
                    <table className="table table-hover">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Code</th>
                          <th>Prenom</th>
                          <th>Nom</th>
                          <th>Email</th>
                          <th>Telephone</th>
                          <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        {clients &&
                          clients.length &&
                          clients.map(client => (
                            <tr key={client.clientid}>
                              <td>{client.Code} </td>
                              <td>{client.Prenom}</td>
                              <td>{client.Nom}</td>
                              <td>{client.Email}</td>
                              <td>{client.Telephone}</td>
                              <td>
                                <a>Edit</a>|<a>Delete</a>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          ))}
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ListeClients;
```

My router is :

```
    exports.listeclients = function(req, res) {
         var clientid = req.body.clientid;
        var Code = req.body.Code;
        var Prenom = req.body.Prenom;
        var Nom = req.body.Nom;
        var Email = req.body.Email;
        var Telephone = req.body.Telephone;


        connection.query('SELECT Code, Prenom, Nom, Email, Telephone FROM clients ', function(error, results, fields) {
            if (error) throw error;
res.send(JSON.stringify(results));
            console.log(results);
        });
    }
```

Can you explain me why I can't view the content of my table ?

When I run it, I get :

The error :

```
 Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.

    in tr (at ListeClients.js:65)
    in ListeClients (created by LoadableComponent)
    in LoadableComponent (at DefaultLayout.js:46)
    in Route (at DefaultLayout.js:45)
    in Switch (at DefaultLayout.js:43)
    in div (created by Container)
    in Container (at DefaultLayout.js:42)
    in main (at DefaultLayout.js:40)
    in div (at DefaultLayout.js:32)
    in div (at DefaultLayout.js:28)
    in DefaultLayout (created by Route)
    in Route (at App.js:32)
    in Switch (at App.js:27)
    in Router (created by HashRouter)
    in HashRouter (at App.js:26)
    in App (at index.js:9)
```

How to fix that please ?

Comment: What happens if you remove `clients && clients.length &&` from your render method?

Comment: Thank you @Tholle.  I edit the post, take a look please.

Comment: Are `clientId` unique? It might be `<tr key={client.clientid}>` that is giving you the warning.

Comment: Yes, `clientid` is a primary key of my table `clients`.

Comment: Alright. Did you remove `clients && clients.length &&`? Could you update the question with the code you have now? Also, are you sure the `clients` are in `response.data` in the response? Check that as well.

Comment: I get the content of my table, but it's still the same warning.

Comment: Then I think you are misspelling `client.clientid`. Is is maybe `clientId`?

Comment: But, on my table, I have `clientid` and not `clientId`

Comment: React is complaining that the `key` given to `<tr key={client.clientid}>` is not unique. Make sure that you have spelled it correctly, and that each `tr` gets a unique one. I don't know what else to say.

Comment: Are you selecting the ClientID from the `clients` table? I don't see it in the `SELECT` statement that you have posted.

Comment: as tholle said, add a 'key' to the items like 'key={client.clientid}' or import 'uuid'. Check [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11222)

Comment: @palsrealm My Select statement is : `SELECT Code, Prenom, Nom, Email, Telephone FROM clients`

Comment: @CodeLover shouldn't the select statement be `SELECT clientid, Code, Prenom, Nom, Email, Telephone FROM clients` ?

Comment: @Mario  I edit `<tr key={client.toString()}>`  it works well, without warning !

Comment: @CodeLover you're welcome. For the reputation in stackoverflow, to accept the anwer would be nice. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as tholle said, add a 'key' to the items like

```
key={client.clientid}
```

or install UUID

```
npm install uuid
```

More Information why [HERE](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)